# joining two dataframes and extending the contents of one of them

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],columns=['x'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[100,200,300]],columns=['y','w','z'])
```

How can I join both dataframes by extending `df2` to match the rows of `df1`?

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
x   y   w   z  
1  100 200 300
2  100 200 300
3  100 200 300
```

Comment: try df1.join(df2).ffill()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple as you saw `assign`

```
df1.assign(**df2.iloc[0])
Out[413]: 
   x    y    w    z
0  1  100  200  300
1  2  100  200  300
2  3  100  200  300
```

Comment: kwarg-fu!   Unpacking a pd.Series.  Nice!  +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use join as @Vaishali mentions of your index of your dataframes are the default range index.   Where the index of your second dataframe, df2, matches the first index of df1.  However, creating a temporary key and doing a merge to create a cartesian product is a little more robust.

```
df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1)).drop('key', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   x    y    w    z
0  1  100  200  300
1  2  100  200  300
2  3  100  200  300
```